# I want to draw one element out from a tibble variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, tibble

I have a dataframe that consist of multiple variables, and some of them are tibbles.
i have variables like:

> [ID, name, symbol, category, urls,....,slug]

In this case slug is a tibble and consist of multiple urls of interst such as [Website, facebooksite, twitter,..,reddit]

I would like to draw out only webpage for each asset as a new variable.

So far I figured out I can get the webpage for

```
ID=1 data$urls[[1]][1,] and for ID=2 crypto.info1$urls[[2]][1,]

output is
A tibble: 1 x 2
  name    url                 
  <chr>   <chr>               
1 website https://bitcoin.org/
```

but I want for every ID in a new variable. I hope someone can assist me.

```
Data example:
| ID |  Name   |Category |   Urls    |
| -- | --------|---------|-----------|
| 1  | Bitcoin |Coin     |2 variables|
| 2  | Litecoin|Coin     |3 variables|
| .  | ........|......   |...........|
```

when urls is opened it looks like:
Data example:

```
|  Name   |              url           |
| --------|----------------------------|
| Website |https://bitcoin.org/        |
| Reddit  |https://reddit.com/r/bitcoin|
| ........|......                      |
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Share a `dput()` of your data so we can see exactly how it's structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urls <- c()

for(i in 1:length(data$urls)){

urls[i] <- data$urls[[i]][1,2] 
}
data$Website <- urls
```

Thanks to Bensstats send me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

With lack of context, you can use a for loop. Since you just want the website you can edit the indexing slightly like how I did in the code below.

**Disclaimer:** I have not ran this code, if you see an error please let me know.

**Also:** I know this is with a for loop and not vectorized.

```r
urls <- c()

for(i in 1:length(data$urls)){

urls[i] <- data$urls[[i]][1,2] 
}
```

If I understand your problem correctly, with the above code `urls` will be a vector of the websites extracted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it was almost perfect i edited it an reposted as answer, many thanks for the help. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the made-up example, here's an alternative approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Made-up data
df <- tribble(~id, ~name, ~url,
        1, "website", "bitcoin.org",
        1, "twitter", "#this",
        2, "website", "bitcoin.net",
        2, "twitter", "#that",
        3, "website", "bitcoin.biz",
        3, "twitter", "#other",
        ) |> 
  nest(slug = -id)

# Pluck the url
df |> mutate(website = map_chr(slug, pluck, "url", 1))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>      id slug             website    
#>   <dbl> <list>           <chr>      
#> 1     1 <tibble [2 × 2]> bitcoin.org
#> 2     2 <tibble [2 × 2]> bitcoin.net
#> 3     3 <tibble [2 × 2]> bitcoin.biz
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>